# Is there a way to obtain a TensorFlow js model from a TensorFlow SavedModel using the TensorFlow Java API without using Python?

Tags: javascript, java, python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am looking for a way to convert a tf saved model into a tf javascript model using the Java API (no Python). The main thing that I am interested is obtaining the JSON with the information of the architecture and the model.